# How to remove an iTunes Wi-Fi Sync host

Tags: itunes, ipad, wifi, data-synchronization

I open settings, pick General, iTunes Wi-Fi Sync, and it has two hosts listed.  The older host does not exist any more.  The newer host says "Books" so I assume it is just syncing Books and not the rest of the iPhone's data.

How can I remove the older host and get all of my data synced to the newer host?

iOS 10.3.1 on an iPad Mini 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to start wifi syncing with a new computer, you must first attach your iPad, over your charging cable, to the computer with iTunes running. Then select 'Sync this iPad over Wifi' in the Options in the iPad Summary screen in iTunes.

To get rid of a sync 'host', you need to connect your iPad to iTunes on the host, then deselect 'Sync this ipad over wifi' in the Options of the iPad Summary of iTunes.

Having one 'host' does not impact the ability to sync over wifi to another one. The iPad will sync with whatever machine is online and available over wifi. If the older host no longer exists, this won't impact syncing your iPad to the new computer at all, and other than connecting it to that computer, there is no way to remove that item on your Ipad.

Comment: Part of this answer isn't correct but it did help me so I checked it.  Here is my full saga: the particular piece that I wanted sync was Music and it was going to the old Mac.  I did a "Ease All Content and Settings"... actually what I did was follow Apple's instructions on how to sell an old iPad.  Then it still was not happy because I had no content so I enabled some content.  The screen changed to the right screen but was dimmed.  I did a reboot and now it works.  It says "books, music, and podcasts" will be sync whereas before it just said books.